# gcloud command to retrieve metadata of a specific key

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

Is there any way to retrieve custom instance metadata value for a specific key ?
I tried `gcloud compute instances describe instance-1` command, this return whole meta data text. But i just want to retrieve the value of a specific key only.

Comment: Have you tried using the google cloud REST api?

Comment: Yes i tried that from google sdk, but where i face an authentication issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `gcloud` tool has built-in filters and formats, for details you can read [`gcloud topic filters`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters), [`gcloud topic formats`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats), and [`gcloud topic projections`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections).

For your specific use case, you can get the metadata value with:

```
gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE-ID \
  --format='value[](metadata.items.YOUR-KEY)'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this -- exactly what I was looking for + had been trying to recreate. What does the `[]` do there exactly? Seems to return the result fine even without that.

Comment: The `[]` are for the arguments. Indeed, they are not required in this instance, but I like to keep the brackets as a good practice to show I'm passing no arguments, and to avoid forgetting them when I need to pass them.